# access virtual machine using samba

Tags: virtualbox, samba

I have ubuntu 16.04 running in virtual box on my windows 10 host.I want to access the files within my guest os from my host os using samba. Currently I have a NAT adapter attached to my guest OS.I installed samba on ubuntu and added the following to smb.conf.

[image: samba configuration]

I restarted samba and tried accessing from my windows using \\10.0.2.15\share (10.0.2.15 is my ubuntu ip) but it does not open.I tried bridged mode network,setting static ip address but nothing works. If you could please provide the steps to do this correctly I would be greatful.

Comment: FYI: 10.0.2.15 seems like a "local" address. This is probably not accessible from your host. You should receive another IP address, if you set the network adapter to `Bridged Adapter`. Try that IP.